# How to mock the global variable using rewire?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, istanbul

i want to mock values to these global variables from my test class

```
//index.js
                        /* Globals variables */
    var documentLoaderGlobal = {
    region: process.env.ElasticSearchRegion,
    endpoint: process.env.ElasticSearchEndpoint,
    index: process.env.ElasticSearchIndex,
    mapping: process.env.ElasticSearchMapping,
    dynamoDBTable:process.env.DynamoDBTable
    };
```

my test class is

```
var rewire = require("rewire");  
var myModule = rewire("./index.js");
var region="us-east-1";
myModule.__set__("documentLoaderGlobal.region", region);
```

when i run the test case, the values is not getting mocked .

Any idea what am i doing wrong ? or am i missing something ?